# How to work as a team with Microsoft Visual C# and SQL server centralized database and single Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Here is my scenario. I wants to do a project using Microsoft Visual C# 2013 and SQL server database. This project is a group project. So that I want to work every member on same project with same centralized database. What are the technologies I have to use and How to do those configurations.

Comment: By centralized database do you mean a database that your application will use or version control system? If you want good answers you should try to explain what exactly you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to use [TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx). And [create database project using visual studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245612/Creating-a-Database-Project-with-Visual-Studio). Then maintain your local database. And TFS for version controlling and source sharing among group members.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate you help. I think way you mention is best way to do this

Comment: OP asked for _"with same **centralized** database"_ not  _"Then maintain your **local** database"_.  Why _"TFS"_?  What makes it _"better"_ than other SCM products such as SVN; Mercurial; or GIT?  Consider expanding your answer even though it is accepted by the OP for future readers

Comment: Because TFS is more supportive for Visual Studio...

Comment: @SaveendraSriEkanayake All SCM products I mentioned can be accessed from within VS.  Shucks, even VS has native support now for Git.  TFS is terribly expensive and not as mature as other systems

Comment: @Micky Duncan I know other SCM are also support but. If you are using visual studio sql server then, those things are expensive too. I am using TFS I used GIT also I know the difference in user experience. So if he like he can have it...

Comment: @SaveendraSriEkanayake  SQL Server is a requirement here and is considerably cheaper than rolling out an ALM {  _SQL Server; SharePoint server; 1x Office per user;  seats for TFS_} - just for TFS.  I know, we did it and undid it.  All I said was _"why TFS"_.  VS has native support for it but that's probably about it.  Maybe expand more in your answer?

Comment: @Micky Duncan  So then its better to use java my sql and git..

Comment: @SaveendraSriEkanayake `Please don't attempt to post your foul language on my blog Mr 103.247.50.151 @ Sri Lanka`.  Was I mean to you in any way? Grow up!

Comment: @Micky Duncan If you are victim of any kind of harassment then i am very sorry. I don't want to waste my time to do these kind of thing. If i want to use foul language why should i do it in here. I'll tell what i want here. I am really sorry about it bro. I don't want to argue with you.

Comment: I ask the question because I didn't knew what to do. I did not care about pricing or comparison. I got an answer. I searched for that. I felt it much more comfortable. Nothing to argue about the which one expensive or which one cheap. So if other way is better you Micky Duncan help me with better solution rather wasting time on arguing angrily